# CheckBoxes inside a GridView stop responding after soft-keyboard

Tags: android

I use a grid view that gathers several check boxes. The grid view is populated using an adapter that is derived from BaseAdapted. Above the grid there is an EditText.

The check boxes function ok in the beginning. But after showing the soft keyboard (by tapping the EditText, then dismissing the keyboard, even without pressing any key) some of the check boxes that were covered by the keyboard stop responding.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials I gave up the `GridView` and used instead a `TableLayout`, creating the `TableRow`s dynamically. No softkeys problem with this solution, it looks exactly the same and behaves the same as a `GridView` (except for the entire check boxes set is loaded into memory, which might not be the case with a `GridView`, but still all check boxes were displayed on the activity at once so I don't think there was any memory consumption difference).

In short, `TableLayout/TableRow` instead of `GridView` for this purpose looks the same, and even easier to code, since I filled up the `TableLayout` directly, within a few lines of code, where the `GridView` required an adapter. Problemo solved, case closed. :-)